# Como alterar nome fechado e cor vermelha pelo nome aberto e cor azul ao clicar no nome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body{
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            font-size:10vw;
        }
        .aberto {background-color: #1a72e6;}
        .fechado {background-color: #ff5252;}
    </style>
</head>
    <body class="fechado">
        <div class="container text-center m-auto p-5">
            <p>Fechado</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando JavaScript para verificar a situação atual, não está muito dinâmico, mas funciona!

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function() { // evento da tag <p> ao ser clicada!
  if (this.innerHTML == 'Fechado') { // verifica se o conteúdo presente na tag <p> é "Fechado".
    this.innerHTML = 'Aberto'; // sendo assim, ele altera seu conteúdo para "Aberto".
    document.querySelector('body').className = 'aberto'; // incluindo a classe (para assim realizar as alterações, como cores, etc..)
  } else { // caso contrário, seja diferente de "Fechado"
    this.innerHTML = 'Fechado'; // o conteúdo da tag <p> é alterado para "Fechado"
    document.querySelector('body').className = 'fechado'; // incluindo sua classe.
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body{
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            font-size:10vw;
        }
        .aberto {background-color: #1a72e6;}
        .fechado {background-color: #ff5252;}
    </style>
</head>
    <body class="fechado">
        <div class="container text-center m-auto p-5">
            <p>Fechado</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Espero que o tenha ajudado. Bons estudos!!

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Disponha, selecione minha resposta como "Aceita e Funcional", fica abaixo dos Votos, ao lado das respostas, na sua esquerda. Qualquer dúvida só falar! forte abraço!

Answer (score 2):

> Pode ultilizar Jquery e ficará da seguinte forma

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
  <style>
        body{
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            font-size:10vw;
        }
        .aberto {background-color: #1a72e6;}
        .fechado {background-color: #ff5252;}
    </style>
</head>
    <body class="fechado">
        <div class="container text-center m-auto p-5">
            <p id="name">Fechado</p>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
         
         $(document).ready(function(){

          $("#name").click(function(){
            
            var name = $("#name").text();

            if(name == 'Fechado'){
                $('#name').text("Aberto");
                $("body").attr('class', 'aberto');
            }else{
                $('#name').text("Fechado");
                $("body").attr('class', 'fechado');
            }

          });
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Um grande abraço, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção só com CSS usando `label` e um input `checkbox`. Isso vai dar muito mais semântica para o seu código e ainda não precisa importar jQuery ou mesmo se preocupar so o JS do browser do usuário está ativado ou não. Além disso, são itens de `form` e vc pode manipula-los tranquilamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10vw;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.aberto {
  background-color: #1a72e6;
  display: block;
}
.fechado {
  background-color: #ff5252;
  display: none;
}

#ok {
  display: none;
}
#ok:checked ~ .fechado{
  display: block;
}
#ok:checked ~ .aberto{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="ok">
  <label for="ok" class="fechado container text-center m-auto p-5">
    <p>Fechado</p>
  </label>
  <label for="ok" class="aberto container text-center m-auto p-5">
    <p>Aberto</p>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado! um grande abraço.

Comment: Sem problemas meu caro, fico feliz em ter ajudado